# Keeping a program going on an external server

Tags: python, ssh

I have an external server that I can SSH into. It runs bots on reddit.

Whenever I close the terminal window the bot is running in, the process stops, which means the bot stops as well.

I've tried using

`nohup python mybot.py`

but it doesn't work - when I close the window and check the processes (`ps -e`), python does not show up. Are there any alternatives to nohup? Ideally, that print the output to the terminal, instead of an external file.

Comment: run it in the background. `python mybot.py &`

Comment: I'm still having the same problem. The server is an amazon ec2 free tier setup - does this make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using tmux/screen? They have lots of features and can help you detach a terminal and re-attach to it at a later date without disrupting the running process.

Comment: Perfect - I ended up going with screen